# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, flatmap

I need to make multiple calls.

**1. Delete Document Upload**

**2. Image 1 & server returns URL**

**3. Upload Image 2 & server returns URL**

**4. Create Document API contains both URLs & extra

        parameters.**

The code which I tried to write is in RxSwift,& MVVM.

```
  let resultOfDocumentUpdateWithDelete =
            donepressed
                .filter{ $0 }
                .withLatestFrom(self.existingDocumentIDChangedProperty)
                .flatMapLatest {id in
                    let deleted_document = apiClient.deleteDocument(id).asObservable().materialize()
                    let upload_frontImage = deleted_document
                        .withLatestFrom(self.frontImageNameChangedProperty)
                        .flatMapLatest {image in
                            apiClient.uploadImage(image: image!).asObservable().materialize()
                    }
                    let upload_backImage = upload_frontImage
                        .withLatestFrom(self.backImageChangedProperty)
                        .flatMapLatest {image in
                            apiClient.uploadImage(image: image!).asObservable().materialize()
                    }

                    let upload_document = upload_backImage
                        .withLatestFrom(self.parametersChangedProperty)
                        .flatMapLatest {parameters in
                            apiClient.uploadDocument(parameters: parameters)
                    }

                    return upload_document.materialize()
                }
                .share(replay: 1)
```

Make sure, two responses of server are input in last API, so all of these will be called in a sequence.

how to do in RxSwift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting one! The take-away here is that when you are in doubt, go ahead and make your own operator. If it turns out that you later figure out how to do the job using the built-in operators, then you can replace yours. The only thing with making your own is that they require a lot more testing.

Note, to use the below, you will have to combineLatest of your observables and then flatMap and pass their values into this function.

```
// all possible results from this job.
enum ProcessResult {
    case success
    case deleteFailure(Error)
    case imageFailue(Error)
    case backImageFailure(Error)
    case documentFailure(Error)
}

func uploadContent(apiClient: APIClient, documentID: Int, frontImage: UIImage, backImage: UIImage, parameters: Parameters) -> Single<ProcessResult> {
    // instead of trying to deal with all the materializes, I decided to turn it into a single process.
    return Single.create { observer in

        // each api call happens in turn. Note that there are no roll-back semantics included! You are dealing with a very poorly written server.
        let deleted = apiClient.deleteDocument(id: documentID)
            .asObservable()
            .share()

        let imagesUploaded = deleted
            .flatMap { _ in Observable.zip(apiClient.uploadImage(image: frontImage).asObservable(), apiClient.uploadImage(image: backImage).asObservable()) }
            .share()

        let documentUploaded = imagesUploaded
            .flatMap { arg -> Single<Void> in
                let (frontURL, backURL) = arg
                var updatedParams = parameters
                // add frontURL and backURL to parameters
                return apiClient.uploadDocument(parameters: updatedParams)
            }
            .share()

        let disposable = deleted
            .subscribe(onError: { observer(.success(ProcessResult.deleteFailure($0))) })
        let disposable1 = imagesUploaded
            .subscribe(onError: { observer(.success(ProcessResult.imageFailue($0))) })
        let disposable2 = documentUploaded
            .subscribe(
                onNext: { observer(.success(ProcessResult.success)) },
                onError: { observer(.success(ProcessResult.documentFailure($0))) }
        )

        return Disposables.create([disposable, disposable1, disposable2])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for details proper answer with use of zip and single method.